# how to transfer a file in a particular directory of FTP server using libcurl

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl

Iwant to transfer a file to a particular directory on FTP server . If it does not exists on the server then it has to be created there and file will be placed .

Platform : Linux , gcc compiler 
Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the [ftpupload](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpupload.html) example in `libcurl`.